# How do I get both Service Object and ServiceReference, when using declarative services

Tags: java, osgi

I need both ServiceReference and Service Object when I'm using my Bundle in osgi. However, when I do it as showed by the code below, my bundle can no longer find the bind method. what am I doing wrong?

```
public class AServiceImpl implements AService{

    TestService t;
    JournalService journalService;
    BundleContext context;
    ServiceReference testServiceRef;

    public void bindTestService(TestService testService, ServiceReference sv) {
        t = testService;
            testServiceRef = sv;
        //this.testServiceRef = testServiceRef;
        test.api.TestStaticVariable.getUniqueInstance().add("TEST A");
        System.out.println(test.api.TestStaticVariable.getUniqueInstance().toString());
    }

    public void unbindTestService(TestService testService){
        System.out.println("");
        if(t.equals(testService)){
            t = null;
        }
    }

    public void bindJournalService(JournalService journalService){
        this.journalService = journalService;  
    }

    public void unbindJournalService(JournalService journalService){
        if(this.journalService.equals(journalService)){
            this.journalService = null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See section 112.3.2 of OSGi compendium 4.3 at https://osgi.org/download/r4v43/osgi.cmpn-4.3.0.pdf.

So just use the `ServiceReference` and get the object through the component context as described in 112.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found a proper working solution to the problem:

I just use the BundleContext, retrieved from the activate method. There, I use the method:

```
testServiceRef = context.getServiceReference(TestService.class);
```

where the TestService is retrieved from the bind method.

Comment: Actually, it is better to have the ServiceReference injected in the bind method and then call
```testService = context.getService(testServiceRef)```
Make sure to also unget the service in the unbind method.

Comment: Can you clarify why it is better?

Comment: Because DS injects the BundleContext and the ServiceReference. You just need to get and unget the service. Your proposal of getting the ServiceReference ignores DS's binding of the service to your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the bundle of any class using [FrameworkUtil#getBundle](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/FrameworkUtil.html#getBundle(java.lang.Class)) from which you can get [BundleContext](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getBundleContext()). Then from BundleContext you can get [ServiceReference](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReference(java.lang.Class)) using which you can finally [get the service instance](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getService(org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference)) from BundleContext API.

```
    import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
    import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
    import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;
    import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

    public class GetServiceDemo {

        public static ResourceResolverFactory getResourceResolverFactory(){
            Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ResourceResolverFactory.class);
            BundleContext bundleContext = bundle.getBundleContext();
            ServiceReference<ResourceResolverFactory> resourceResolverFactoryServiceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ResourceResolverFactory.class);
            ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory = bundleContext.getService(resourceResolverFactoryServiceReference);
            return resourceResolverFactory;
        }
    }
```

ResourceResolverFactory is a registered service.